# Initializing 2D array in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a problem with initialzing a 2D array in python. I want a 6x6 array, I did

```
arr = [[None]*6]*6
```

But when I do:

```
>>> arr[1][2]=10
>>> arr
[[None, None, 10, None, None, None], [None, None, 10, None, None, None], [None, None, 10, None, None, None], [None, None, 10, None, None, None], [None, None, 10, None, None, None], [None, None, 10, None, None, None]]
```

Notice I just set 1 item, and its "replicated" on all rows. Whats wrong? I think it has to do with its referencing the same list, but how do I fix this?

I figured

```
for key, _ in algos.items():
    algoData[key] = []
    for i in range(0,6):
        algoData[key].append([])
        for j in range(0,6):
            algoData[key][i].append(None)
```

works, but it seems long to just initialize an empty 6x6 array, what if I want a 10000x10000 array, it will be very inefficient?

**UPDATE**

Can I also initialize a dictionary of 2D arrays? I have a dictionary like:

```
algos = { "FIFO": ..., "LRU": ..., "Random": ... }
```

I want to initialize a dictionary like below:

```
algoData = { "FIFO": 2D arr, "LRU": 2D arr, "Random": 2D arr }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using list comprehensions, you can say:

```
arr = [[None for x in range(6)] for y in range(6)]
```

Then you will have `arr[1][2] = 10` working as expected. This is not a very normal thing to do, however. What are you going to use the nested lists for? There may be a better way. For example, working with arrays is made much easier with the numpy package.

Comment: I want to store data for use with matplotlib (a 3D surface plot)

Comment: In that case, I would definitely recommend numpy. It is used in [this example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/animation/simple_3danim.html), if you want to see a sample. Save yourself the work; it is a great package.

Comment: So the line I need will be just `lineData = np.empty((dims, length))`?

Comment: Also can I initialize a dictionary of 2D arrays in a similar way (maybe the one in your answer)? I updated my original question

Answer (score 19):

@Cameron is correct in suggesting that you use NumPy to deal with arrays of numerical data. And for the second part of your question, ~Niklas B. is spot on with his suggestion to use `defaultdict`.

What hasn't been covered is *why* `[[None]*6]*6` behaves strangely.

The answer is that `[None]*6` creates a list with six `None`s in it (like you expect), but `[list]*6` does not make six independent copies of `list` - it makes six copies of a *reference* to the *same* `list`.

*Idiomatic Python* has a section that may explain this better: ["Other languages have variables - Python has names"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables).

Answer (score 0):

```py
arr = [[None for i in range(6)] for j in range(6)]

arr[1][2] = 10

arr
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please format your code properly using the formatter provided. Also, do remember to give some explanation to your code or comment it to explain your code properly to other users.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to initialise an array with zeros, and then push values to the respective indices.

```
black_array = np.zeros((10,10))
```

returns black_array of dimensions 10*10 with zeros