# Python matrix shared values of rows

Tags: python, matrix, shared

So i have a question to create a matrix, but I'm unsure why the values are shared? Not sure if its due to the sequence being a reference type or not?

If you write this code in pythontutor, you'll find that the main tuple all points to the same 'row' tuple and is shared. I understand that if I did `return row*n` it'd be shared, but **Why is it that when you concatenate tuples, or append lists, why would it then be shared (referred to the same memory address)**?

```
def make_matrix(n):
    row = (0, )*n
    board = ()
    for i in range(n):
        board += (row,)
    return board

matrix = make_board(4)
print(matrix)
```

As compared to this code, where each row is separately (0,0,0,0) and not shared.

```
def make_board(n):
    return tuple(tuple(0 for i in range(n)) for i in range(n))

matrix = make_board(4)
print(matrix)
```

Comment: This is just the way the language works: `[hex(id(x)) for x in (0,) * 3] #=>
['0x5fb0d1c0', '0x5fb0d1c0', '0x5fb0d1c0']`. You can see anything that is multiplied is still one reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializing 2D array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954183/initializing-2d-array-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

When you multiply a tuple, you're not actually multiplying its contents. You're creating references to its memory address. Thus, if you edit the contents of the original variable, all variables that share its memory address are changed too.

Comment: yes, what I'm asking actually is why concatenating tuples and appending lists create the same references to this memory address

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you have created a tuple once and add it multiple times to your matrix:

```
row = (0, )*n
for i in range(n):
    board += (row,)
```

In the second example you are creating new tuples for each addition:

```
tuple(0 for i in range(n)) for i in range(n)
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
for i in range(n):
    row = tuple(0 for i in range(n))
    board += (row,)
```

So when the same tuple is append multiple times you "share" it multiple times.