# Initializing one row of 2d array initializes the whole 2d array

Tags: python

I've initialized a 2d array and then tried to initialize all the values of the first row to 0.

```
saved_results = [[None] * (c + 1)] * (len(v) + 1)

for i, j in enumerate(saved_results[0]):
    saved_results[0][i] = 0
```

Instead of

```
[
[0, 0, 0],
[None, None, None],
[None, None, None]
]
```

I get

```
[
[0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0]
]
```

I'm not sure if I'm overlooking something simple. What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9956306/7421710

Comment: @Zoro Yes! Thank you

Comment: Here is another answer with more upvotes. https://stackoverflow.com/a/240205/7421710