# Changing the same element in all lists in a 2D-array

Tags: python, arrays

When doing something like for example:

```
arr = [[0]*3]*3
arr[1][0] = 4
```

It will alter the first element in all three lists. Is this because we are only making a copy of the first list and the elements share the same pointer in memory?

That is, the first list is for example:

`[A,A+C,A+2C]` where C is the Offset and A is the address to the first value.
And the construction above creates a list:
`[[A,A+C,A+2C], [A,A+C,A+2C], [A,A+C,A+2C]]`
Ergo, if we change any element in any position of one of the lists, we alter the corresponding the the other lists?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954183/initializing-2d-array-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly. The repeat command `*3` Makes a shallow copy, in all instances. Something to watch out for. I personally have been bitten by this in initialization, e.g.

```
a, b = []*2
```

Makes a and b refer to the same object.